# Appending list to a list does not generate list of lists

Tags: python, list

I feel like i've done this multiple times but for some reason this isn't producing the output i'm expecting.

Code Snippet:

```
for dup in sorted(list_duplicates(video_list)):
    for dup_element in dup[1]:
        output_array.append(video_titles[dup_element])
    output_array_array.append(output_array)

print(output_array_array)
```

The output of list_duplicates takes an array of arrays and returns a set of tuples. Example below:

```
[
('1-3A.mp42-1.mp43-3.mp44-1.mp45-1.mp46-1.mp47-7.mp46-2.mp48-1.mp49-2.mp410-2.mp411-3.mp4', [1, 3]),
('1-3B.mp42-1.mp43-3.mp44-1.mp45-1.mp46-1.mp47-7.mp46-2.mp48-1.mp49-2.mp410-2.mp411-3.mp4', [2, 4])
]
```

The expected output from the for loop is a list of lists that should look like:

```
[['Week 3 Day 2', 'Week 3 Day 4',], 
 ['Week 3 Day 3', 'Week 3 Day 5']]
```

Instead I get:

```
[['Week 3 Day 2', 'Week 3 Day 4', 'Week 3 Day 3', 'Week 3 Day 5'],
 ['Week 3 Day 2', 'Week 3 Day 4', 'Week 3 Day 3', 'Week 3 Day 5']]
```

I believe the error is coming from `for dup_element in dup[1]:` loop and where i've placed the `output_array.append` but I can't seem to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please fix the indentation errors in your code (`list_duplicates` function).

Comment: IndentationError and missing data, please [edit] and fix it to be a real [mre] we can work with.

Comment: There aren't any type annotations in this code so it's hard to infer what's going in and what's coming out.  Could you provide an example of what `video_list` and `video_titles` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reinitialize `output_array` in the outer loop:

```
for dup in sorted(list_duplicates(video_list)):
    output_array = []  # moved from three lines up
```

Now you are appending the same list over and over again.

Comment: Thanks this solved it. Editing my question to specifically focus on the specifics of the issue.